# inner join ot returning results from second and third tables

Tags: php, arrays, inner-join

I am baffled as to what I am doing wrong. I've looked this up in many resources, including the book that I am learning PHP out of, and it seems like it should be right...but it is just not working.

```
<?php

try
{
    $sql = 'SELECT parks.id, parks.state, parks.name, parks.description, parks.site, parks.sname, parks.street, parks.city, parks.zip, parks.phone FROM parks
INNER JOIN comments ON parks.parkid = comments.parkid
INNER JOIN photos ON parks.parkid = photos.parkid 
INNER JOIN events ON parks.parkid = events.parkid';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error fetching data: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $datas[] = array ('id' =>$row['id'],
    'parkid' =>$row['parkid'],
    'state' =>$row['state'], 
    'name' =>$row['name'], 
    'description' =>$row['description'], 
    'site' =>$row['site'], 
    'sname' =>$row['sname'],
    'street' =>$row['street'], 
    'city' =>$row['city'], 
    'phone' =>$row['phone'],
    'zip' =>$row['zip'],
    'commentname' =>$row['commentname'],
    'comment' =>$row['comment'],
    'event' =>$row['event'],
    'date' =>$row['date'],
    'description2' =>$row['description2']);
}

include 'writing.html.php';
```

This returns all of the data that is in the first table (parks) just fine. The items commentname, comment, event, date, and description2 are from the joined tables (events and comments)

If I echo '$row['state']' I get a correct answer. But if I echo any of the items from the other tables (for instance $row['comment']) I get no result.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're not listing columns from any of the joined tables to return

Comment: Mark, I don't understand your answer. Where should I list them other than in the array? They are in the array.

Comment: The array is built from the $result returned by SQL in $row... but if your $sql doesn't list the columns, then they won't be in $row... see answer below for an example of listing the columns, not a complete solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL showing how to return columns from the joined tables

```
SELECT parks.id, 
       parks.state, 
       parks.name AS park_name, -- use an alias when column names exist in more than one table
       parks.description, 
       parks.site, 
       parks.sname, 
       parks.street, 
       parks.city, 
       parks.zip, 
       parks.phone,
       comments.comment, -- to return the comment from the comments table
       events.name AS event_name, -- return name from the event table
       event_date  -- return date from the event table
  FROM parks 
  INNER JOIN comments 
          ON parks.parkid = comments.parkid 
  INNER JOIN photos 
          ON parks.parkid = photos.parkid  
  INNER JOIN events 
          ON parks.parkid = events.parkid'
;
```

This is not a complete solution, but a demonstration of ho to return data from the joined tables rather than purely from the main table

Comment: WOW That is exactly what I was looking for. It worked. Thanks so much. I've been trying this for days now, you are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write the query to return them...

```
<?php

try
{
    $sql = 'SELECT parks.id, parks.state, parks.name, parks.description, parks.site, parks.sname, parks.street, parks.city, parks.zip, parks.phone 
    --insert here any other column names you want to have in PHP
    FROM parks
    INNER JOIN comments ON parks.parkid = comments.parkid
    INNER JOIN photos ON parks.parkid = photos.parkid 
    INNER JOIN events ON parks.parkid = events.parkid';
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
```

Or you could just get all (**beware**, if there are columns in the tabl;es that have the same name, this won't work!):

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM parks
    INNER JOIN comments ON parks.parkid = comments.parkid
    INNER JOIN photos ON parks.parkid = photos.parkid 
    INNER JOIN events ON parks.parkid = events.parkid';
```

Comment: I am trying to get all of the data. I am sorting and displaying it in the include. Each table does have a column called id. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
try
{
    $sql = 'SELECT parks.id, parks.state, parks.name, parks.description, parks.site, parks.sname, parks.street, parks.city, parks.zip, parks.phone FROM parks
INNER JOIN comments INNER JOIN photos INNER JOIN events ON parks.parkid = comments.parkid and parks.parkid = photos.parkid and parks.parkid = events.parkid';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: try this query directly in database

Comment: The did the same thing that my original code did. $name['phone'] returns correctly, $name['comment'] returns nothing. I checked, and there are entries for "comment" for each park id, so that's not the problem...